# Delay code execution in VCL Forms Application

Tags: sorting, c++builder

Need to animate a sorting algorithm, with source code line by line visualization.

***INTRO:***

For the begining, there is a FORM (see it in the picture attached). On top of that form is displayed a dinamicaly created array of Edit components, containing the array to sort.
A little below, on the right is placed a Memo component, containing the algorithm. At the left of each line of that algorithm, dinamicaly is placed a Label, that indicates the line number in algorithm.

The idea is to highlight line by colouring that label, where is the execution at the moment. Sorting starts when "Start" button is clicked. The action for it is following:

```
int n = 10;
bool swapped = true; hl(1);
int j = 0; hl(2);
int tmp; hl(3);
while (swapped) { hl(4);
    swapped = false; hl(5);
    j++; hl(6);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++) { hl(7);
          if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) { hl(8);
                tmp = arr[i]; hl(9);
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1]; hl(10);
                arr[i + 1] = tmp; hl(11);
                swapped = true; hl(12);
          } hl(13);
    }  hl(14);
}  hl(15);
```

The **hl** function must colour labels and pause execution by using Sleep() function

```
void TForm2::hl(int l)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
         Form2->lines[i]->Font->Color = clGray;
    }
    Form2->lines[l-1]->Font->Color = clRed;
    Sleep(300);
}
```

***PROBLEM:***

Code execution is pausing (sleep function works properly), but the labels are still gray, with no visible changes, except the last one, when event finishes. The 15th line is red.

***QUESTION:***

Can anybody tell me, where I'm wrong, and how to do it right?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/crGyC.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allow the paint message to be processed in order to visually update the display. You can do that with either the `Refresh` or `Update` procedures:

```
Form2->Lines[l-1]->Font->Color = clGray;
Form2->Update();            // or Form2->Refresh();
```

Comment: `Update()` is typically better to use because it processes pending paint messages only if there are actually paint messages waiting to be processed.  `Refresh()`, on the other hand, forces full repaints even if nothing has changed.